# Unity2d Every object is invisible

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I was working on my first project on Unity2d and after like 7 hours of progress, I had a big problem. Every object (Characters, Background, Ennemies) were invisible. I know they are still there because if I select them, their box collider show up. Unfortunately, I didn't find any answer so I hope you got one...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unless you can show some relevant set-up code, this question is purely about software problems.

Comment: Are you running high sierra per chance? Unity has had some notable issues like this. What Unity version are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10 and Unity 2017.4.0f1

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is a Sprite renderer enabled and attatched to the objects.

Comment: Omg it was that. Thanks! I feel kinda dumb though.

Comment: make sure you accept this answer as correct @DaGreenDoritos

Answer (score 0):

2D games only use the X and Y axis.

Your Z axis is in the negatives and its behind the scene.

Comment: This should be posted as comment // from Review